# oledb is not opening in php

Tags: php, sql

For read word document using php,i installed "php_oledb.dll" file in C:\xampp\php\ext folder. After that its showing below error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oledb_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mallikarjuna\test\parsing5\test1.php on line 6
```

Answer (score 1):

After adding a new extention/library in the good directory, I think you have to enable it in the `php.ini`

Adding a new line to use this dll

You should find some example in the `php.ini` file, this should be like:

```
extension=php_extname.dll
```

Reboot the PHP, this should be ok. If this is not ok, take a look at the PHP error log, sometimes, an extension requiered some other things/configs.